# How to load Image and text in multiple GridView without having outofMemory error

Tags: android, gridview

I have a layout that it has 12 `GridViews` on it. I have almost 150 images that i must load them in `GridViews`.For every `GridView` almost 12 images. When i want to load images and texts in 2 of `GridViews`, there is not any problem. But when i want to load images in 3 or more, `outofmemory` error occur. This is my codes for load images and texts in `gridview1`.

```
    final GridviewAdapter mAdapter;    
    final GridView  gridView0 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


            final ArrayList<String> listCountry;
            final ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

              listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
              listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();



          listCountry.add("text1");
          listCountry.add("text2");
          listCountry.add("text3");
          listCountry.add("text4");
          listCountry.add("text5");
          listCountry.add("text6");
          listCountry.add("text7");
          listCountry.add("text8");
          listCountry.add("text9");
        //
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w1);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w12);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w15);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w26);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w28);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w33);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w44);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w46);
          listFlag.add(R.drawable.w50);

mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(FirstPageActivity.this,listCountry, listFlag);
                                                                                                gridView0.setAdapter(mAdapter);`
```

all of `GridViews` has codes like this,only difference is in images and texts. And I use this codes inside `onCreate` method. When i un comment codes of `GridView3` and later `outofmemory` error occurs and exit from app. I searched about this, and someone says use `lazyloading` or `asynctask` but i do not know how to solve this problem. I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: is there any problem with my question that no one wants to answer

Answer (score 0):

Two points: First, if your images are full screen resolution, and you are going to show 150 of them on screen at once, and never have any need to show them in full resolution, go resize them. They are consuming far more memory than you need. If you intend to show all of them on screen at once, they are just thumbnails.

Second, if you aren't going to show all 150 on screen at once, you shouldn't try to load everything into memory simultaneously. How you do that depends on how you are showing these. If you really are trying to show all 150 on screen at the same time, then your images are too big and consume too much memory. You will need have a thumbnail version that you display in your grid and a full size version that you display in a full view (assuming you have a full view).

If you are only trying to show a portion, only load that portion, plus a buffer in either direction (if they are in a scrollable list). You can tell where you are in the list because scrollable lists fire onScroll events, and ArrayAdapter's getView method will tell you the positions of the views it is loading.

If this does not answer, edit your question to contain a screenshot or a UI mock of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you Kevin. you are correct. i do not need to load images simultaneously. i can and i want to load them when user scroll to down. i load them simultaneously because i can not load them when user scroll. in fact i am weak to do this;( . as you know all of gridviews is not in physical screen and user must scroll down to see them. i want when user see gridview(i) -(i from one to twelve) images load. thanks you for your help.